# Why is this query not working when another is present?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, owl-carousel

This is driving me nuts, I'm sure it's something stupid but I'm too burnt and can't find it. I'm building a custom WP theme which has 2 sliders, one is the default Bootstrap slider and the other is an Owl Slider. Before you tell me "why don't you use 2 instances of Owl slider?", I already thought of that, tested and works. However, I'm very curious as to why is this not working. Here's my code:

**BOOTSTRAP Carousel:**

```
<section id="panel4">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Testimonials</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php $queryObject=new WP_Query( 'post_type=testimonial' ); // The Loop! if ($queryObject->have_posts()) { ?>
    <div id="carousel-testimonial" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {$queryObject->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item ">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 thumb-box">
                <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo types_render_field( " testimonial-avatar ", array( url => "true ", "width " => "400 ", "height " => "300 ", "proportional " => "true " ) );?>">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                <h3>"<?php echo types_render_field("testimonial-excerpt", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));    ?>"</h3>

                <blockquote>
                  <?php echo types_render_field( "testimonial-text", array( "argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2")); ?></blockquote>
                <p class="sig">
                  <?php echo types_render_field( "testimonial-name", array( "argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2")); ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-testimonial" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-testimonial" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- .carousel -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</section>
```

**and then OWL SLIDER**

```
<?php if( have_rows( 'slider_photos') ): ?>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="happy" class="owl-carousel">

    <?php while( have_rows( 'slider_photos') ): the_row(); // vars $image=g et_sub_field( 'slider_image'); ?>
    <div class="item-owl">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>
  <!-- .carousel -->
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, the problem seems to be in Bootstrap. If I take it off, Owl slider works. If I add 2 instances of Owl Slider, it works. If I add Bootstrap Carousel, only Bootstrap works and Owl displays nothing (not even in code, it's as if it didn't even exist)

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe a JavaScript conflict? Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I thought of that, but no errors at all, just like it doesn't exist

Comment: more info: if I place the Owl slider **before** Bootstrap Carousel, it also works, it just doesn't work as I have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` before `have_rows( 'slider_photos')` in the *Owl slider*, to restore the global `$post` object, that you override in your *Bootstrap carousel* loop.

The `have_rows('slider_photos')` depends on the global `$post` object.

Another option would be to use  `have_rows( 'slider_photos', $post_id )` to specify what `$post_id` you want to use.

Comment: Wow, didn't think about it but yes, quite possibly this is the reason, will test it tomorrow at the office but quite positive this is the correct answer

Comment: yes, thank you, it was that, I totally forgot to mark this as correct, my bad!